# Bash: How to get the call chain on errors?

Tags: bash

I have a back trace function in bash that works well enough (code below) but the problem is that bash itself when it hits an error, it doesn't give a back trace or any kind of info that would help determine the caller, which can help in debugging the issue.

e.g.:

> ./c.sh: line 23: urgh: command not found

```
function backtrace () {
    local deptn=${#FUNCNAME[@]}

    for ((i=1; i<$deptn; i++)); do
        local func="${FUNCNAME[$i]}"
        local line="${BASH_LINENO[$((i-1))]}"
        local src="${BASH_SOURCE[$((i-1))]}"
        printf '%*s' $i '' # indent
        echo "at: $func(), $src, line $line"
    done
}
```

Is it possible to trap bash on such errors so I could call my own function to get output like this?

```
 at: c(), ./c.sh, line 22
  at: b(), ./c.sh, line 11
   at: main(), ./b.sh, line 5
```

Update: final working version from suggestions and traceback trap on error:

```
function backtrace () {
    local deptn=${#FUNCNAME[@]}

    for ((i=1; i<$deptn; i++)); do
        local func="${FUNCNAME[$i]}"
        local line="${BASH_LINENO[$((i-1))]}"
        local src="${BASH_SOURCE[$((i-1))]}"
        printf '%*s' $i '' # indent
        echo "at: $func(), $src, line $line"
    done
}

function trace_top_caller () {
    local func="${FUNCNAME[1]}"
    local line="${BASH_LINENO[0]}"
    local src="${BASH_SOURCE[0]}"
    echo "  called from: $func(), $src, line $line"
}

set -o errtrace
trap 'trace_top_caller' ERR
```

Comment: What's the purpose behind the weird quoting on your echo? `echo "at: $func(), $file, line $line"` would be simpler and more correct.

Comment: Not an answer to your question but that indent function is extremely inefficient. `printf '%*s' $d ''` will do the same thing and can be combined with your echo line even.

Comment: Not to mention that you don't need those local variables at all (though they aren't hurting anything).

Comment: ...also, all-uppercase locals generate needless potential for namespace collisions; better to follow convention, and reserve all-uppercase names for environment variables and internal shell use.

Comment: As an answer to your question a `trap` on `ERR` might do some of what you want.

Comment: I have not attempted it, but in trying to follow the call chain backwards beyond script invocation, the only wrapper that looks promising is with `coproc` with `wait`. Not being familiar with it beyond the description in the bash man page, you will need to asses whether defining a `coproc` to your script can allow you any additional insight into the call chain. That would at least give you some way to work at getting to `$((DEPTH+=1))`. Interesting question.

Comment: By the way, while there's kibitzing going on here, use of the `function` keyword isn't a great habit to be in -- it's gratuitously incompatible with POSIX, but adds no tangible benefit over the POSIX sh-compatible way of declaring shell functions, `backtrace() {` with no preceding `function`. I'm all for bash extensions when they have some benefit, but `function` is not onesuch.

Comment: Thanks for the style comments too, folks, Duly noted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely -- this is exactly what error traps are for:

```
trap backtrace ERR
```

In the past, I vaguely recall finding it necessary to make that something more like `trap 'backtrace "${#BASH_SOURCE[@]}" "${BASH_SOURCE[@]}" "${#BASH_LINENO[@]}" "${BASH_LINENO[@]}"' ERR` to work around a bug (and reading array values off the function's argv); however, I don't remember at present just what that bug would be and which versions it impacted.

Comment: If the trap is declared inside an offending function, then this works well and I see the call stack. However if the trap is declared at the global level and the error is inside a child function, then we only get the traceback for the top most caller. I'm not sure if this is intentional by design with the trap. Seems you would have to declare the trap at the start of each function.

Comment: @NeilMcGill, there's a shell option which determines whether error traps are inherited. I don't remember it offhand, but it's well-documented.

Comment: @NeilMcGill, `set -E`, or `set -o errtrace`.

Comment: From someone suffering this illusion a long time — bash cannot be tamed that way. You'll be lulled into thinking that trapping `ERR` works 100% of the time. But then, you use `if <bashfunction-invocation>; then... fi` and it bites you right in your whatever: ERR traps are not invoked in `if`, `while`, ... so if you'd want to go there sometime, better quit this __now__, not only sometime down that road. Just a warning to the ambitious but not yet wise user.
Reference: went on to implement a full-fledged scoping library similar to bash-oo (bash-infinity on github).